# Como configurar o OwinContext Authentication no SimpleInjector 3.3.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, simple-injector

Em minha aplicação atual uso o SimpleInjector 3.2.0 com uma configuração similar a essa:

```cs
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

container.Register<IUserStore<Usuario>>(() => 
    new UserStore<Usuario>(container.GetInstance<IContext>() as DbContext), 
    Lifestyle.Scoped);

container.Register<AppUserManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<AppSignInManager>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

// demais serviços
SimpleInjectorContainer.RegisterServices(container);

container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() =>
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && 
        HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null && 
        container.IsVerifying())
        return new OwinContext().Authentication;

    return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
});

container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

container.RegisterMvcIntegratedFilterProvider();
container.Verify();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

Sei que esse trecho para configuração do Authentication do  OwinContext está obsoleto.
Como configurá-lo com o SimpleInjector 3.3.2?

E essa configuração para o IUserStore<>.
Estou usando o próprio container para obter uma instância do DbContext.
Passa pelo Verify(), mas será que estou realmente pegando a instância de IUserStore<> por essa configuração?

Muda alguma outra coisa a mais para a versão 3.3.2?
Estou usando .Net 4.6.1